# php consultas a base de datos, no retorna valores

Tags: php

Quiero traer de la tabla usuarios un mail. Es una base de datos local, y accede bien a ella porque en la condición esta corroborado. Tengo un input, que debo colocar un mail, y buscar el mail que coloque en el input en la base de datos y que coincidan.

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['operar'])){
    if (strlen($_POST['entrada']) > 9){  //valida que el campo no este vacio y que sea mayor de 9
        if ($linkConexion!=false){
            $var = $_POST['entrada'];
            $sql = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = ' " . $var . "'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($linkConexion, $sql);
            while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
                if(strcmp($registro,$var) == 0) {//si devuelve 0 son iguales. Se compara cadenas de tx
                    ?> 
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <p class="m-none text-semibold h6">
                    Listo! Tu cuenta se encuentra activa nuevamente. </p>
                    </div>
                    <?php 
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-warning"> 
                    <p class="m-none text-semibold h6">
                    <p class="m-none text-semibold h6"> Ingrese un Email correcto </p>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
            }
        } else {

        }
    } else {

    }
} 
?>
```

para mi el error esta en el **while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){**

Comment: Posiblemente el error esté en la linea `if(strcmp($registro,$var) == 0)` Debe ser `if(strcmp($registro[0],$var) == 0)` Recuerda que mysqli_fetch_array trae un arreglo con índice numérico de elementos, producto de la consulta.

Comment: Una cosa más para añadir es que ese código es vulnerable a SQLInjection. Si no filtras $var = $_POST['entrada']; Mírate esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el problema parece estar en la linea de sql:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = ' " . $var . "'";
```

tienes un espacio en blanco entre la ' y la ", deberia ser:

```
$sql = "SELECT email FROM usuarios WHERE email = '" . $var . "'";
```

Por ello, en la linea siguiente el `mysqli_query` te esta devolviendo un `$rs = null`:

```
$rs = mysqli_query($linkConexion, $sql);
```

y por tanto tu linea de while da error, porque mysqli_fetch_array esta recibiendo como parametro un null:

```
    while ($registro = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)){
```

Comment: Excelente! todo por un espacio. Gracias!!! Ahora a la hora de compilar, larga un error en la linea de comparación de cadenas. if(strcmp($registro,$var) == 0)

Comment: Warning: strcmp() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: La función `strcmp` pide una cadena, pero el `mysql_fetch_array` devuelve un Array. En este caso con cambiarlo por `strcmp($registro['email'], $var)` debería arreglartelo